# Can someone help me to prove the orthogonality in continuous case for Bessel Functions?

Tags: orthogonality, dirac-delta, bessel-functions, continuous-variables

I already prove the orthogonality condition of Bessel functions for discrete case ($0,b$).

$$\int_0^{b}\rho J_{\nu}(\chi_{\nu l}\rho/b)J_{\nu}(\chi_{\nu l'}\rho/b)d\rho = \frac{b^2}{2}[J_{\nu+1}(\chi_{\nu l})]^2\delta_{ll'}$$

Now, I need to prove that the orthogonality condition of Bessel Functions in the continuous case ($0,\infty$) can be written as:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\rho J_{\nu}(k\rho)J_{\nu}(k'\rho)d\rho = \frac{1}{k}\delta(k'-k)$$

With $\chi_{\nu l} = kb$ and $\chi_{\nu l´} = k'b$. But I don't know how to do it.
Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I made 'b' tend to infinity, this changes the Kronecker delta to a Dirac delta then I replace this on the orthonormality condition for discrete basis but I don't get the same expression that I put in the question for the continuous basis.